# run function on next page based on which link is clicked

Tags: javascript, function, hyperlink, load

i have a page "mysite.com/NUMBERS" [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/shqpA/4/) with the click function to change the class of the numbers. how would i make it so links on "mysite.com/HOME" which has just the numbers "1 2 3 4 5" on it and if you click "1" it will bring you to "mysite.com/NUMBERS" and run `$(#1).addClass('numOn');` so the "1111111" is active on page load, if you click "2" the numbers page it load `$(#2).addClass('numOn');` and so on. is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using a cookie or using `#` suffixes on the URL? (e.g. "mysite.com/HOME#1"?

Answer (score 1):

You could add data to the URL after a hash tag and check for it on page load with javascript.

i.e. mysite.com/NUMBERS#1 on page load check for it with:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    //call the 'addClass' method on the appropriate ID
}
```